# Changing sound effect on a function when variable changes

Tags: javascript, html, audio, soundeffect

I'm writing a homework assignment for a JS class, and the teacher wants us to have a weapon sound when firing, but stop making sound when out of ammo.
I have the sound effect working for when the gun fires, but it continues making the sound when clicked with 0 ammo.

I tried doing an else{} function, but this breaks the "ammo display" in my browser, and the sound would continue playing anyway.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Heal" class="shoot" onclick="shoot();">
<audio id="heal" src="sound/heal.mp3">
```

JS: Displays ammo starting at a maximum of 6 shots, with 6 shots in reserve, and counts down each time it is fired.

```
function shoot() {
  if (currentAmmo > 0) {
    currentAmmo--;
  }
  var shoot = document.getElementById("shoot");
  shoot.play();
  updatescreen();

  function updatescreen() {
    document.getElementById("total-ammo").innerHTML = "Bullets in Gun:</br>" + totalAmmo;
    document.getElementById("current-ammo").innerHTML = "Reload Ammo:</br>" + currentAmmo;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move the play command inside the if-condition.

```
  if (currentAmmo > 0) {
    currentAmmo--;
  var shoot = document.getElementById("shoot");
  shoot.play();
  }

  updatescreen();
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the `play` call inside your `if` statement, so it plays only if the statement is true:

```
function shoot() {
  if (currentAmmo > 0) {
    currentAmmo--;
    document.getElementById("shoot").play();
  }
}
```